# Which SAP table do I need to find annual sales?

Tags: calculation, sap-erp, database-table, sap-bw

I don't know much about SAP but I need the annual sales (the total amount of what was sold in a certain year) for DSO calculation. In which SAP table is this stored? VBAK?

Also for this calculation the accounts receivables (all payments that were not paid by customers in the fiscal year) is needed. I use BSID and BSAD tables, is that correct?

I hope someone can help me. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

There are [many standard SD reports](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/10/19/sap-sd-standard-reports/) which fit your needs. For accumulated sales data you can use `MC+E` and `MC+2` which refers to invoiced sales and per-customer aggregated sales correspondingly.

[image]

Also you can inspect `VC/2` standard report which represent customer fact sheet data including account receivables

[image]

What concerns particularly receivables, there is a good transaction `S_ALR_87012167` which also includes DSO analysis for receivables as well as evaluation by different metrics.

[image]

[image]

What concerns the tables, this data lays in multiple tables including VBAK, VBAP, BSID, BSAD, etc., so it wouldn't be easy to grab them manually. You should analyze the code of corresponding transaction to reveal how it calculates the data.

I'd rather stick to extracting data directly from transaction, rather than digging into the tables, as you may just repeat the efforts (aka reinvent the wheel) that SAP put into developing these standard reports.